# Installing CUDA 11 in Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvida GTX 1060

Tags: dpkg, 20.04, cuda, ubuntu-mate

I recently tried installing [CUDA 11.0 for Ubuntu 18.04](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) in Ubuntu Mate 20.04, following the instructions on the [website](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation). I tried to to install CUDA in text mode (runlevel 3) by running `sudo apt-get install cuda` and I get an error about not being able to install `libnvidia-compute-450`. So I run `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` and I get:

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386
  libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libllvm9:i386 libnvidia-common-440
  libnvidia-extra-440 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-450
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-450
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
75 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 322258 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-allocator.so', which is also in package libnvidia-extra-440:amd64 440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)error code (1)
```

On my previous Ubuntu installation I had a similar problem and the only way to fix it was to select and install the previous drivers (nvidia-440). Is there any way around it?

Comment: the error says "you may have broken packages".  Did you update/upgrade your system before trying to add new software?  (you should always do this).  What happens when you run `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`.  Please include not just the error message, but the command you issued that gives you this message.

Comment: The system was fully upgraded before trying to install CUDA, it was a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I did try `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`.

Comment: Check out the errors: see how it says `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required` and lists a bunch of packages followed by `Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.`  Please run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up these unused packages.  Report back with the output.

Comment: There was a problem with the `libnvidia-compute-450` package. I managed to solve it by forcing its installation with `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libnvidia-compute-450`. Taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40278#issuecomment-642397545). Drivers and CUDA works fine now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue. [capm's comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2119626) worked for me.

> There was a problem with the `libnvidia-compute-450` package. I managed to solve it by forcing its installation with `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libnvidia-compute-450`. Taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40278#issuecomment-642397545). Drivers and CUDA works fine now.